# Wild cursor on ASUS laptop

Tags: cursor

ASUS laptop---cursor goes to the top right corner of the screen intermittently.  Have not been able to locate the cause.  Very intrusive when typing.  Just upgraded to the current version of W-10.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it do it with a usb mouse?

Comment: There are at least three versions considered to be current and supported. What version of Windows 10 are you using exactly.  Have you installed the current drivers for your touchpad?

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions here, also be sure drivers (BIOS, Chipset, Video and Mouse) are all up to date.

Comment: And look for moisture or contaminants on a trackpad, even if using a mouse.